# Why in First order logic, Variables mapping is not included in Structure definition

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Although the constants are included in Structure definition and Interpretation definition, but Varibles are included only in Interpretation definition, what is the reason for that, is there any error when Variables mapping is included in the Structure definition? is there any logic book, which explains the answer? Can anyone help me?

Comment: The same variable name can mean different things in different formulas, because variables are bound by quantifiers. Do you understand how a sentence like $\forall x.P(x)$ is interpreted in a structure?

Comment: In Structure there are only mapping for constants, functions and relations, but there is no interpretation for these, In Term-Interpretation there are Interpretations for constants, variables and functions, therefore i can not understand how quantifier is interpreted although we do not mention the domain of the variables in the structure like constants

Comment: To interpret your formula we eleminate the $\forall$ through a constant symbol, but we must know the domain of the variable to know which constant symbol can eleminate the $\forall$ quantifier, and that is my question, why variables mapping is not included in the structure definition like constant?

Comment: Every quantifier has the same domain, namely the domain of the structure. So $\forall x P(x)$ holds in the structure iff $P(c)$ holds for every element $c$ of the structure (abusing notation slightly to let $c$ be a constant referring to the element $c$ of the model).

Comment: Because writing $R(x)$ is like writing "it is Red". What is the reference of the pronoun "it"? It depends on the context (I'm writing it now with a red pen on my desk). Thus, an intepretation is the "world" outside us: it is fixed, while a variable assignemnt is a way to set a context.